# Fréchet mean for a general shape space

Tags: probability, general-topology, complex-analysis, metric-spaces

I am posting this question in order to gain a better understand of what the *Fréchet mean* is for a generalised shape space.

So firstly I gather that the Fréchet mean of a probabilty measure $\mu$ on a general metric space $(M,dist)$ is a generalisation of the mean or the expectation of a probability distribution on a Euclidean space and is defined as *any global* minimum of the function
$$F(x)=\int_Mdist(x,y)^2d\mu(y).$$
This concept can be further generalised by replacing 'dist' in the integrand by a suitable function of the distance.

My question is, what exactly does this formula do? I think it has something to do with minimising the mean between a data set, however I am not sure of this. Also I am not sure how I would *use* this formula. What exactly is the 'probability measure' in this case? I think it's some kind of statistical distribution, but again I am really not sure.

Any help with this question will be much appreiciated, thank you.

Comment: If $x^*$ is an argument of a global minimum of $F$, then we know that the $\mu$-average distance from $x^*$ to any point $y\in M$ is minimal.

Comment: Thank you, so $x^*$ is the argmin of F, would we consider $y$ to be the argmin of another data set? And what exactly is the $\mu$-average? I.e. what is a probability measure?

Comment: In order to have any concept of a mean we need a probability measure. When finding the mean of numbers $1,2,3,4$ we (implicitly) use the probability measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(\{k\})=1/4$ for $k=1,2,3,4$. So, if you need the mean of a finite subset of a metric space, using this soft of measure (normalized counting measure) may be appropriate. If the set is infinite, one has to think harder of what the appropriate measure should be.

Answer (score 0):

It is always useful to consider a simple example. For example, consider the uniform distribution on $M = [0,1]$ and Euclidean metric $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$. We know that the (usual) mean is $1/2$. So let's check. We aim at minimizing
$$
F(x) = \int_0^1 ||x-y||^2 dy = \int_0^1 (x-y)^2 dy = x^2y-xy^2+y^3/3 \big|_{y=0}^1 = x^2 - x.
$$
It is easy to see that this function attains it's minimum at $x=1/2$.

More general, if the distribution has probability density $p$, we want to minimize
$$
F(x) = \int_M ||x-y||^2 p(y) dy
$$
We compute the minimum by setting the derivative to zero:
$$
d/dx F(x) = \int_M d/dx ||x-y||^2 p(y) dy =  \int_M 2(x-y) p(y) dy \\= 2 x \int_M p(y) dy - 2\int_M y p(y) dy = 2x - 2\int_M y p(y) dy = 0
$$
The last equality is equivalent to
$$
x = \int_M y p(y) dy
$$
Hence, we have shown that if $d$ is the Euclidean metric, the Fréchet mean of a distribution with density $p$ coincides with the usual mean of this distribution $x = \int_M y p(y) dy$

Even more general, there need not be a density, you may want to use the abstract formulation using a probability measure $\mu$
$$
F(x) = \int_M ||x-y||^2 d \mu(y)
$$